# Are component hierarchy changes forbidden during a Swing drop callback?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I noticed that if I do `removeAll()`, `add()`, `revalidate()` while handling a drop [`DropTargetListener.drop()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/dnd/DropTargetListener.html#drop(java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDropEvent)), the drop will succeed and the changes will take effect but I won't be able to start a second drag ever. Any subsequent drag attempt will throw a `java.awt.dnd.InvalidDnDOperationException: Drag and drop in progress`
.

It seems that if do changes to the hierarchy the drag will not be cleared, and Swing thinks that there is still one ongoing drag pending completion. This happens even when the hierarchy changes are after calling `DropTargetDropEvent.acceptDrop()` and `DropTargetDropEvent.dropComplete()`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.dnd.*;
import javax.activation.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.util.TooManyListenersException;


class MyWidget extends JComponent {

    MyWidget() {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        updateState();
    }

    void updateState() {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // System.out.println("Hello World on " + Thread.currentThread());
                removeAll();
                add(newButton("aaa"));
                add(newButton("bbb"));
                revalidate();

            }
        };
        if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
            runnable.run();
        } else {
           SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
        }

    }

    JButton newButton(String text) {
        JButton theButton = new JButton(text);

        DragSource ds = new DragSource();
        DragGestureRecognizer dgr = ds.createDefaultDragGestureRecognizer(theButton, DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY, new DragGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public void dragGestureRecognized(DragGestureEvent dge) {
                Transferable transferable = new DataHandler("my text", "text/plain");
                dge.startDrag(DragSource.DefaultCopyDrop, transferable);
            }
        });

        DropTarget dt = new DropTarget();
        dt.setComponent(theButton);
        try {
        dt.addDropTargetListener(new DropTargetAdapter() {
          @Override
          public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
            System.out.println("drop accepted");
            dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
            dtde.dropComplete(true);
            updateState();
          }
        });
        } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {}
        return theButton;
    }

}

public class App 
{
    static void createGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("my app");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new MyWidget(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        // frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Hello World on " + Thread.currentThread());
                createGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the component hierarchy change occurs while the drag is not completed yet. After calling `DropTargetDropEvent.dropComplete(true)` the drop may be completed but not the drag part. There are callbacks on the drag side that potentially could run in the EDT after the current `DropTargetListener.drop()` (which what the EDT is currently running) returns control to the EDT main loop.

So the component hierarchy changes have to be delayed so that they are run after the drag operation is completed.

So instead of

```
if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
    runnable.run();
} else {
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
}
```

just run

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable); // unconditionally
```

that will schedule that runnable to run after the drag, because the `dropComplete()` has already scheduled an event in the EDT event queue to handle the drag completion. So the `invokeLater()` will put the code that changes the component hierarchy after the event that will mark the drag as completed.